# How do I use jqGrid with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have just started using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/), and I have some tables that I would like to display within it.

Can anyone tell me what the proper way would be to populate this grid using ASP.NET MVC?  How do I pass information from my controller to the jqGrid?  Does it need to be a particular format?

If anyone can provide some information regarding ASP.NET MVC + jqGrid I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your actions will return JSON typically.

Blog posts all over. Check [here](http://techshorts.blogspot.com/2009/04/json-for-jqgrid-from-aspnet-mvc.html), [here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/14/38200/) and [here](http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2008/08/aspnet-mvc-and-jqgrid.html) for the how to's

Answer (score 4):

Craig Stuntz has a good [series on jqGrid](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/tag/jqgrid/) as well, covering a variety of topics for it.

Answer (score 2):

The best example in my opinion is phil hacck's ["Using jQuery Grid With ASP.NET MVC"](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx). Phil also has a downloadable example you can play with.

Answer (score 0):

Full dynamical jQGrid integration with asp.net MVC including bootstrap design is explained here http://www.techdoubts.net/2017/05/full-integration-dynamic-jqgrid-asp-net-mvc.html. Only required data is fetching from server side, it will increase you website speed.